# Last Saturday date in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to find last Saturday date in HIVE in YYYY-MM-DD format using:

```
SET DATE_DM2=date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),cast(((from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'u') % 7)+1) as int));
```

But this is giving error

Comment: write the string into a tmp file, i.e. generate a Hive script using Python, and then call hive on that file. quick, dirty, simple but should work. Also, check your quotes.

Comment: I am new to hive and python. Can you please give example/syntax ?

Comment: ok, you forgot to format the string...that's it. Print your c before calling anything.

Comment: I am not getting ? I printed c but obviously it shows the same line. What formatting ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

`c = "hive -e 'use Data; SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE partitiondate='${DATE_D}';'"`

into:

`c = "hive -e \"use Data; SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE partitiondate='{DATE_D}';\"".format(DATE_D=DATE_D)`

The call to `format` is what @Mai was mentioning. As for printing c, `print c` will show you the value of `c` at runtime, so you'll know if the value is as you expect.

**P.S.** calling `commands.getoutput` will not only fetch the rows but all of the standard output of calling `hive` in command line, and store that in a single string - meaning you'll probably need to do some parsing if you need to work with those rows. Or better yet, check out [HiveClient](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-Python).

Comment: Thanks!! I am trying to retrieve last saturday date in HIVE uisng - SET DATE_DM2=date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),"yyyy-MM-dd"),cast(((from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'u') - 5 % 7)+1) as int)); But it is giving error.. Can you please help

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct if it solved your problem. When you accept answers as correct people are more likely to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: I also see that you've already asked that in a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128776/date-variable-in-hive), I'll answer that there. Please do read up on [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting more questions in the future. It will also make people more likely to answer your questions.