# Date variable in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am using following code to set date in Hive

```
SET DATE_DM2=date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy/MM/dd'), cast(((from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'u') % 7)+1) as int));
```

But When I am running the following select statement I am not getting the output

```
select * from TableName where partitiondate='${DATE_DM2}';
```

Is there anything wrong with the syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Syntax is :

select * from TableName where partitiondate='${hiveconf:DATE_DM2}';